# Are the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_4$ also Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_5$?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, symmetric-groups, prime-factorization, sylow-theory

Here is my thinking:

$|S_4| = 4! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 = 2^3 \times 3$.

$|S_5| = 5! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 = 2^3 \times 3 \times 5$.

Since $2^3$ is the maximal power of $2$ which divides the order of $S_4$ and $S_5$ and since $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_5$, we know that the Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_4$ are also Sylow $2$-subgroups of $S_5$.

Similarly, since $3$ is the maximal power of $3$ which divides the order of $S_4$ and $S_5$ and since $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_5$, we know that the Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_4$ are also Sylow $3$-subgroups of $S_5$.

On the other hand, if we wanted to check whether the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_4$ are also Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_6$ we would see the following.

$|S_4| = 4! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 = 2^3 \times 3$.

$|S_6| = 6! = 1 \times 2 \times 3 \times 4 \times 5 \times 6 = 2^3 \times 3 \times 6 = 2^4 \times 3^2$.

Since $6$ can be decomposed into $2 \times 3$, the maximal powers of $2$ and $3$ are no longer the same in $S_4$ and $S_6$ and so the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $S_4$ are not also $p$-subgroups of $S_6$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No, not quite, since $(1234)\in S_4$ and $(1234)(5)\in S_5$ are different.

Comment: But $S_4$ is a subgroup of $S_5$ isn't it? Meaning that all permutations within $S_4$ are also contained within $S_5$, and so all of the subgroups in $S_4$ will also be contained within $S_5$?

Comment: No, $S_4$ is *isomorphic* to a (number of different) subgroup(s) of $S_5$, since elements of $S_4$ are bijections from $N=\{1,2,3,4\}$ to $N$, whereas elements of $S_5$ are bijections from $M=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ to $M$.

Comment: A careful person will say that for each subgroup of $S_4$, there is an isomorphic copy of that subgroup in $S_5$.  In fact, there are $\binom{5}{4}$ copies of each such subgroup, since permutations of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ are isomorphic to permutations of $\{1,2,3,5\}$ (and so on for the other choices of four symbols from five).

Comment: @EricTowers does that not mean that for one of those choices, the subgroups will be the same? I was asking whether the Sylow $p$-subgroups which exist in $S_4$ are also present in $S_5$, there may be extra in $S_5$ for this to be true.

Comment: The embedding of $\{1,2,3,4\}$ into $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ induces an embedding $S_4\hookrightarrow S_5$ as the permutations fixing $5$. (And any embedding will induce an embedding into $S_5$ as “the permutations that fix $k$”). Under that embedding, the image of a Sylow $2$-subgroup of of $S_4$ will be a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_5$, and similar with the Sylow $3$-subgroups.

Comment: @mathemagic : "the same" is not sufficiently precise to give an answer.  There will be (several) isomorphic subgroups.  However, $S_4$ is the collection of permutations on four objects and $S_5$ is the collection of permutations on five objects.  No element of one is an element of the other.  Every element of the subgroup of $S_5$ that you're probably thinking of has the $1$-cycle "$(5)$" and no element of $S_4$ does.

Comment: Just to confuse the issue, in GAP $S_4$ really is a subgroup $S_5$, because all permutation groups are regarded as acting on the infinite set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  Embed $S_4\hookrightarrow S_5$ and then compose with the inclusion $P\hookrightarrow S_4$.  Once you've a subgroup of the right order,  it's a Sylow subgroup!